# Mixing generators of different dimensionality

Tags: lie-algebra, representation-theory, kaluza-klein

Reading a paper about compactified manifolds used in Kaluza Klein theories the author discusses in which ways you can get $SU(2)\times{}U(1)\times{}U(1)$ as a subgroup of $SU(3)\times{}SU(2)\times{}U(1)$.

At a certain point, it starts considering ways of getting $U(1)$. It says you can do it using the $\lambda_8$ Gell-Mann's matrix as a generator of $U(1)$. The original $U(1)$ group as well can be, of course, used, whose generator he calls $Y$, and finally any of the $U(1)$ generators of $SU(2)$, which he calls $T_3$.

Then he combines the three generators in a linear combination

$p\lambda_8+qT_3+rY$

Which is supposed to be a generator (via complex exponentiation) of a $U(1)$ group.

How is this supposed to be understood? Being all three generators matrices of different dimensionality, how do we add them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [semisimple Lie algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra)

$$L=su(3)\oplus su(2)\oplus u(1)$$

is a [direct sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) of simple Lie algebras. Concretely a Lie algebra element in $L$ may be represented as [block diagonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices) $6\times 6$ matrix, where a $3\times 3$ submatrix, $2\times 2$ submatrix and a $1\times 1$ submatrix carry the $su(3)$ element, the $su(2)$ element, and the $u(1)$ element, respectively.

The corresponding Lie group elements can be reached by exponentiation of the Lie algebra elements.

Comment: so I just make 6x6 blocks and exponentiate? and if $su(3)$ $su(2)$ and $u(1)$ each have a block, when righting, for example, $\lambda_8$ as an element of the Lie algebra you say, the blocks corresponding to $su(2)$ and $u(1)$ should be null blocks?

Comment: It seems you got it.